# Hidden minimizing effect in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, dock

Normally there are two minimizing effect in Mac OS X.

- Genie Effect
- Scale Effect

There is one more effect.

- Which works like we flush water. or like flag like effect. (don't have proper words to explain the effect).

I have seen the effect. When I had installed an additional software, I found this effect.

The software was for enabling hidden features of Mac OS X.

I forgot the name of software & Mac has been crashed. So, I don't have that software now.

Will you help me to find out that hidden minimizing effect?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the minimize effect to any of the three options, type or paste one of the following commands into the Terminal:

- **Suck effect**

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.dock mineffect -string suck
  ```
- **Scale effect**

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.dock mineffect -string scale
  ```
- **Genie effect (Mac OS X Default)**

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.dock mineffect -string genie
  ```

Finally, to activate any of the above settings, you’ll need to reload the Dock by killing it:

```
killall Dock
```

[Source](http://osxdaily.com/2007/04/12/change-the-minimize-effect-in-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Check out Mac Pilot 3 and "Enable Hidden Features and Optimize Your System". Also, don't be afraid to use Google ;) I answered your question just by googling a little bit.